# How to display $date = "2015 05 06 00:00:00"; in php

Tags: php, date

```
$date = "2015 05 06 00:00:00";
```

I need to display like `Wednesday, May 6th, 2015`. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
echo $endDateValue=date('l, F jS, Y',strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
```

Comment: As you have spaces between Y and m and between m and d, you''ll need to let PHP know what your format is: `$endDateValue = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y m d H:i:s', $date); echo $endDateValue->format('l, F jS, Y');`

Comment: read manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   <?php
    $date = strtotime("2015 05 06 00:00:00");



    echo $endDateValue=date('l, F jS, Y',strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
    ?>
```